# Need help on splitting multiple columns merged into one

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

In the excel sheet you can see that three columns have been merged into one. I want to split them into three different columns with the help of Pandas. This excel file is in csv format. If someone can help, I will be highly thankful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWnyI.png)

Comment: in order for the StackOverflow community to help you, please 1) don't post images or links to images 2) provide input data or sample data 3) what you have tried and 4) expected output. This link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hopefully, the below code gives you a push in the right direction. Pass the delimiter "-" or " " or "," or whatever is the separator.
Then, pass "expand=True"
See below...
*import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['1-one-A','2-two-B','3-three-C']})
df=df['a'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df*